# IntelliJ IDEA & JRebel doesn't reload class

Tags: java, plugins, intellij-idea, jrebel

I try to use JRebel plugin for IDEA in simple by structure project:

```
Test/
├── out
│   └── production
│       └── Test
│           ├── App.class
│           └── rebel.xml
├── src
│   ├── App.java
│   └── rebel.xml
└── Test.iml
```

### rebel.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<application xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.zeroturnaround.com" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.zeroturnaround.com http://www.zeroturnaround.com/alderaan/rebel-2_0.xsd">

    <classpath>
        <dir name="/home/ant/Documents/Java_Projects/Test/out/production/Test">
        </dir>
    </classpath>

</application>
```

### Run with JRebel -> App.java:

```
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        for (; ;) {
            System.out.println("Hello jrebel");
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
    }
}
```

### JRebel logs:

```
2014-02-25 17:46:55 JRebel: 
2014-02-25 17:46:55 JRebel: #############################################################
2014-02-25 17:46:55 JRebel: 
2014-02-25 17:46:55 JRebel:  JRebel 5.5 (201312230953)
2014-02-25 17:46:55 JRebel:  (c) Copyright ZeroTurnaround OU, Estonia, Tartu.
2014-02-25 17:46:55 JRebel: 
2014-02-25 17:46:55 JRebel:  Over the last 1 days JRebel prevented 
2014-02-25 17:46:55 JRebel:  at least 0 redeploys/restarts saving you about 0 hours.
2014-02-25 17:46:55 JRebel: 
2014-02-25 17:46:55 JRebel:  You are running with an evaluation license.
2014-02-25 17:46:55 JRebel:  You have 11 days until the license expires. 
2014-02-25 17:46:55 JRebel: 
2014-02-25 17:46:55 JRebel:  You will see this notification until you obtain a 
2014-02-25 17:46:55 JRebel:  full license for your installation. 
2014-02-25 17:46:55 JRebel: 
2014-02-25 17:46:55 JRebel:  Visit www.jrebel.com for instructions on obtaining    
2014-02-25 17:46:55 JRebel:  a full license. If you wish to continue your evaluation  
2014-02-25 17:46:55 JRebel:  please e-mail to support@zeroturnaround.com.             
2014-02-25 17:46:55 JRebel:                                                           
2014-02-25 17:46:55 JRebel:  If you think you should not see this message contact     
2014-02-25 17:46:55 JRebel:  support@zeroturnaround.com or check that you have your   
2014-02-25 17:46:55 JRebel:  license file in the same directory as the JAR file.      
2014-02-25 17:46:55 JRebel: 
2014-02-25 17:46:55 JRebel:  The following plugins are disabled at the moment: 
2014-02-25 17:46:55 JRebel:  * Axis2 plugin (set -Drebel.axis2_plugin=true to enable)
2014-02-25 17:46:55 JRebel:  * Camel plugin (set -Drebel.camel_plugin=true to enable)
2014-02-25 17:46:55 JRebel:  * Click plugin (set -Drebel.click_plugin=true to enable)
2014-02-25 17:46:55 JRebel:  * Deltaspike plugin (set -Drebel.deltaspike_plugin=true to enable)
2014-02-25 17:46:55 JRebel:  * Eclipse RCP Plugin (set -Drebel.eclipse_plugin=true to enable)
2014-02-25 17:46:55 JRebel:  * JBoss7 EJB Plugin (set -Drebel.jboss7_ejb_plugin=true to enable)
2014-02-25 17:46:55 JRebel:  * JRuby Plugin (set -Drebel.jruby_plugin=true to enable)
2014-02-25 17:46:55 JRebel:  * Jersey plugin (set -Drebel.jersey_plugin=true to enable)
2014-02-25 17:46:55 JRebel:  * Log4j2 plugin (set -Drebel.log4j2_plugin=true to enable)
2014-02-25 17:46:55 JRebel:  * Mustache Plugin (set -Drebel.mustache_plugin=true to enable)
2014-02-25 17:46:55 JRebel:  * RESTlet plugin (set -Drebel.restlet_plugin=true to enable)
2014-02-25 17:46:55 JRebel:  * Seam-Wicket plugin (set -Drebel.seam_wicket_plugin=true to enable)
2014-02-25 17:46:55 JRebel:  * Spring Data Plugin (set -Drebel.spring_data_plugin=true to enable)
2014-02-25 17:46:55 JRebel:  * Thymeleaf Plugin (set -Drebel.thymeleaf_plugin=true to enable)
2014-02-25 17:46:55 JRebel:  * VRaptor plugin (set -Drebel.vraptor_plugin=true to enable)
2014-02-25 17:46:55 JRebel:  * Vaadin CDI utils plugin (set -Drebel.vaadin_cdiutils_plugin=true to enable)
2014-02-25 17:46:55 JRebel:  * WebObjects plugin (set -Drebel.webobjects_plugin=true to enable)
2014-02-25 17:46:55 JRebel: 
2014-02-25 17:46:55 JRebel: #############################################################
2014-02-25 17:46:55 JRebel: 
2014-02-25 17:46:55 JRebel: Directory '/home/ant/Documents/Java_Projects/Test/out/production/Test' will be monitored for changes.
Hello java
Hello java
Hello java
...
```

When I change `java` word in output stream on `jrebel`

```
 System.out.println("Hello jrebel");
```

the JRebel doesn't reload changes.

**What's wrong ?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your example, t he execution never goes out of the while loop, hence it never goes out of the method. A method cannot be replaced in the middle of its execution, so to be reloaded the execution should go out of this method first.

Do this:

```
  public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
      Bean bean = new Bean();
      for (; ;) {
        bean.foo();
        Thread.sleep(1000);
      }
    }
  }

 public class Bean {
   public void foo(){
     System.out.println("Hello jrebel");
   }
 }
```

Now you can change anything in Bean class, but not inside the while loop - the class could be reloaded but the method never exits, hence never gets a chance to execute the new instructions.

BTW, don't forget to compile the changed class.

Comment: Thank you for explanation and for a great plugin! Work magic. Also tested under Web application.